# Workflow Is not working for existing records

Tags: workflow, validation, formula-field

I have created a workflow rule(Email to contact on his/her birthday).I have used this `logic____If(Birthdate=today(),True,False)`____

it is working fine and sending an email if I am inserting a record with today birth date. But it is not sending an email when I am editing the existing record.Evaluation criteria which I have selected are also correct.

Comment: What is the evaluation criteria? (Subsequently meet one?)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a glance on below link you will find a solution for your question.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-retroactively-trigger-workflow-on-already-existing-records&language=en_US

Comment: I have used the same logic but still there is a problem

Comment: Which evaluation criteria you are using here

Comment: Use Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited.

Comment: Please do not just post a link as an answer put a quick summary of what is required for the solution. [answer]

Comment: Previous state of record should be not meeting criteria and current state of record should be meeting the criteria then only in current state workflow will fire for Created and edited to subsequently meet the criteria.
So you need to change the criteria as Use Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use evaluation criteria as created, and every time it's edited.

Comment: I am using this criteria "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

Comment: "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria" This criteria I am using

Comment: Change the evaluation criteria to 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited'. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second evaluation criteria(every time its edited) and it shud work for you then